# How to deal with non-English question with an answer

Tags: discussion, languages

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321595/%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB-getelementsbyclassname), which is in Russian, I guess. It is over a year old and has a negative score, but it received an answer, and thus was prevented from auto-deletion. The answer was also accepted.

I'm aware that the normal course of action is to close as "Needs Details or Clarity," but the close votes were invalidated before.

What's the best course of action here? Try to close-vote again? Is there a different course of action if the answer is not accepted?

Comment: "Invalidated" just means that the close review timed out without enough people looking at it. Closing is the correct course of action here, now that you've posted it here on meta it'll probably get closed quickly.

Comment: If you can still vote to close, do so. I just voted to close as unclear. Questions in other languages definitely should not be answered.

Comment: Not sure the duplicate target answers my question fully, but I guess I should: 1. Try to close again, 2. Raise a moderator flag to get the question deleted. Unless someone tells me otherwise, I'll do this next time.

Comment: If the post is closed and you haven't paraded the question on meta you can post a del-pls request in the [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests) chatroom. Keep in mind that for cv-pls requests a question needs to be recently active (<6 months) for it to be accepted in SOCVR.

Comment: @rene Oh, cool, thanks. So in this case, the question would _not_ have qualified for cv-pls because of no activity, but it would have qualified for del-pls. Got it. Will keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: That is correct. Also posts that are under active discussion on meta are exempt from  moderation requests in SOCVR.

Comment: It was deleted on 2021-09-07T19:07:16Z.

Comment: @rene This seems to be a different question than the target, in that it's about questions that already have an accepted answer. The primary argument against leaving non-English posts open is that the OP can't interact with it properly. For an old question with an accepted answer, that argument is moot, and it's not entirely unreasonable that an SME comes in and translates the question. After all, if the question will be useful to future readers, that's worth salvaging I think. BTW, I'm mostly pinging you since you have a gold badge here (I've already voted to reopen).

Comment: @cigien I honestly don't follow that reasoning. The question is not in English, it should have been closed in the first place. That it didn't happen back then is the problem. The rule is: close and delete. Let's stick to that. If it has value it sure will get asked again soon. The dupe applies. You are trying to invent new rules. The current ones are hard enough. Let's first try to properly apply those before we venture into marginally improving content.

Comment: @rene Yes, I understand that the question should never have been asked, or answered, in the first place. I'm definitely not disagreeing with that. But once a question *has been* asked and answered, I don't see why we need to delete it without considering any value it might have.

Comment: There's a lot of questions that should have been closed as soon as they were posted. What you can do now, when you encounter such questions is to cast a close vote and hope that it gets two more votes in the review queue. You should also downvote. If the question doesn't attract a lot of views, then move on. Don't waste too much time on something that can't be easily cleaned up with and doesn't cause that much trouble.